# How to trigger vuetify dialog with vuetify's tab instead of a button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to trigger a vuetify dialog with vuetify's tabs. I am not sure how to achieve that. I have two components, Tabs.vue and Dialog.vue.

From vuetify, the Tabs.vue component is:

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-tabs
      v-model="tab"
      background-color="deep-purple accent-4"
      centered
      dark
      icons-and-text
    >
      <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>

      <v-tab href="#tab-1">
        Recents
        <v-icon>mdi-phone</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab href="#tab-2">
        Favorites
        <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab href="#tab-3">
        Nearby
        <v-icon>mdi-account-box</v-icon>
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>

    <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
      <v-tab-item
        v-for="i in 3"
        :key="i"
        :value="'tab-' + i"
      >
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs-items>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

The Dialog component is:

```
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
      persistent
      max-width="600px"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          Open Dialog
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline">User Profile</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container>
            <v-row>
              <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="6"
                md="4"
              >
                <v-text-field
                  label="Legal first name*"
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="6"
                md="4"
              >
                <v-text-field
                  label="Legal middle name"
                  hint="example of helper text only on focus"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="6"
                md="4"
              >
                <v-text-field
                  label="Legal last name*"
                  hint="example of persistent helper text"
                  persistent-hint
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12">
                <v-text-field
                  label="Email*"
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12">
                <v-text-field
                  label="Password*"
                  type="password"
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="6"
              >
                <v-select
                  :items="['0-17', '18-29', '30-54', '54+']"
                  label="Age*"
                  required
                ></v-select>
              </v-col>
              <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="6"
              >
                <v-autocomplete
                  :items="['Skiing', 'Ice hockey', 'Soccer', 'Basketball', 'Hockey', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Coding', 'Basejump']"
                  label="Interests"
                  multiple
                ></v-autocomplete>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
          <small>*indicates required field</small>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            color="blue darken-1"
            text
            @click="dialog = false"
          >
            Close
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn
            color="blue darken-1"
            text
            @click="dialog = false"
          >
            Save
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

Note that I copied each component from vuetify directly. As you can see to trigger the dialog, vuetify gives the example of using a button which is within the Dialog.vue component, I will paste that part of the code below again:

```
<template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-btn
      color="primary"
      dark
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
    >
      Open Dialog
    </v-btn>
 </template>
```

It's using the `v-slot:activator` to trigger the dialog. However I'm not sure how I can use one of the tabs in Tabs.vue to trigger the dialog from Dialogs.vue instead. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i made a CodeSandbox for you. if this is what you wanted i will explain afterwards what i did. [Check here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-banach-dsdi6?)

ok...

first let's check your structur.
You wrapped `Dialog.vue` in its own component, that means you need to toggle the Dialog On/Off mechanism from outside now, the parent(`Tabs.vue`).

#### Tabs.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-tabs
      background-color="deep-purple accent-4"
      centered
      dark
      icons-and-text
    >
      <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>
      <v-tab href="#tab-1" @change="toggleDialog('recents')">
        Recents
        <v-icon>mdi-phone</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab href="#tab-2" @change="toggleDialog('favorites')">
        Favorites
        <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab href="#tab-3" @change="toggleDialog('nearby')">
        Nearby
        <v-icon>mdi-account-box</v-icon>
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>

    <v-tabs-items>
      <v-tab-item v-for="i in 3" :key="i" :value="'tab-' + i">
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs-items>
    <Dialog <--------------------------- ADDING component Dialog.vue
      :show-dialog="dialog" <----------- PROP the On/Off logic
      :tab-controll="tabControll" <----- PROP the "which tab is selected"
      @close-dialog="dialog = false" <-- TOGGLE Off on "close" button
      @save-dialog="dialog = false" <--- TOGGLE Off on "save" button
    />
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import Dialog from "@/components/Dialog";
export default {
  components: {
    Dialog,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tab: 0,
      dialog: false, <--------- CONTROLLS the On/Off mechanism inside Dialog.vue
      tabControll: "None Tab",<- CONTROLLS which tab is selected in Dialog.vue
      text: "some text i guess",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDialog(tab) {
      this.tabControll = tab;
      this.dialog = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

each `v-tab` got his very own `changed` event, that's why you need to listen to it on each `v-tab`.

```html
<v-tabs
      background-color="deep-purple accent-4"
      centered
      dark
      icons-and-text
    >
      <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>
      <v-tab href="#tab-1" @change="toggleDialog('recents')"> <------- @change
        Recents
        <v-icon>mdi-phone</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab href="#tab-2" @change="toggleDialog('favorites')"> <------- @change
        Favorites
        <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab href="#tab-3" @change="toggleDialog('nearby')"> <------- @change
        Nearby
        <v-icon>mdi-account-box</v-icon>
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
```

now lets look at the `toggleDialog` function

```js
methods: {
    toggleDialog(tab) {
      this.tabControll = tab;
      this.dialog = true;
    },
  },
```

it does nothing else then toggle the `dialog` in your `data` to true and sets a `tabControll` to let your `Dialog.vue` know which tab was clicked.

#### Dialog.vue

now we prepare `Dialog.vue` to handle the outside controlled behaviors.

```html
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px"> <--------- HERE
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline">User Profile - {{ tabControll }}</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container>
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                <v-text-field label="Legal first name*" required></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                <v-text-field
                  label="Legal middle name"
                  hint="example of helper text only on focus"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                <v-text-field
                  label="Legal last name*"
                  hint="example of persistent helper text"
                  persistent-hint
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12">
                <v-text-field label="Email*" required></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12">
                <v-text-field
                  label="Password*"
                  type="password"
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                <v-select
                  :items="['0-17', '18-29', '30-54', '54+']"
                  label="Age*"
                  required
                ></v-select>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                <v-autocomplete
                  :items="[
                    'Skiing',
                    'Ice hockey',
                    'Soccer',
                    'Basketball',
                    'Hockey',
                    'Reading',
                    'Writing',
                    'Coding',
                    'Basejump',
                  ]"
                  label="Interests"
                  multiple
                ></v-autocomplete>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
          <small>*indicates required field</small>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="$emit('close-dialog')">
            Close
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="$emit('save-dialog')">
            Save
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: this.showDialog,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    showDialog: function () {
      this.dialog = this.showDialog;
    },
  },
  props: {
    showDialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    tabControll: {
      type: String,
      default: "none",
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

we stay consistent and we don't use the `showDialog` prop in our `v-model="dialog"`, otherwise we got a warning that we mutate props without the knowing of the parent (`Tabs.vue`)

```html
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
```

instead we do bind the incoming prop data into our `dialog` inside data

```js
data() {
    return {
      dialog: this.showDialog,
    };
  },
```

now we do not mutate props from outside and we just copy the state of the dialog which is handled from `Tabs.vue`

if you now click on a Tab the event will toggle this `showDialog` into true and this will change the `dialog` inside your data also to true and show the Dialog.

so far so good... now we need functionality to turn the dialog off again.

as i said a multiple times, mutating props is a bad thing, we fire an [$emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) and we tell `Tabs.vue` to close the dialog again.

```html
<v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="$emit('close-dialog')">
  Close
</v-btn>
<v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="$emit('save-dialog')">
  Save
</v-btn>
```

back to

#### Tabs.vue

we listen to those custom events and we toggle the `dialog = false`
right here

```html
<Dialog
      :show-dialog="dialog"
      :tab-controll="tabControll"
      @close-dialog="dialog = false" <-- TOGGLE Off on "close" button
      @save-dialog="dialog = false" <--- TOGGLE Off on "save" button
    />
```

Comment: @MarkShaio added explanation

Comment: this is very detailed, I would give you more votes if I could